# Composite primary key in Entity of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose i need to create a table (entity) which id and name as primary key (composite primary key). How can i create a entity with hibernate using annotation in order to support it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial on composite primary keys in Hibernate:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-hibernatejpa/

Comment: thank you. that is based on JPA annotation right. Is there a way to use it with hibernate specific annotation or way?